# TYPO3 6.2: Tab "Appearance" disappeared (maybe caused by t3sbootstrap extension?)

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, typo3, typo3-6.2.x

When editing an image content element in TYPO3, usually there is a tab "appearance" with options for image size, alignment, position etc. In my installation that tab is not showing, but instead a "nameless" tab. I'm using the t3sbootstrap extension and this behaviour might be caused by bootstrap.

Does anyone know how I can make the appearance tab visible and usable again? I've searched the internet but didn't find anything helpful so far. Thanks for your help!

Here is a screenshot from my backend:
[image: appearance tab is missing]

Comment: If it is caused by "Bootstrap", it is caused by a TYPO3 extension adding some Bootstrap functionality, not by Bootstrap itself. Please clarify that in the question (which extension are you using)?

Comment: Is this administartor's or editor's view? Has editor access to any field from Appearance tab? If it's admin's view clearly some extension 'damaged' the default TCA, analyze the TCA using System > Configuration mod, and/or disabling  last installed extensions one by one (do not forget to clear SYSTEM cache each time)

Comment: @lorenz It is the t3sbootstrap extension like I mentioned in the text. I will clarify by adding it to the title.

Comment: @biesior Thank you! It is the admin's view. Analyzing the TCA and comparing it with another working installation helped me solve the problem. I will post my solution as an answer in case anyone else is having the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently this problem is caused by a corrupted TCA. I made the following changes in default TCA using System -> Configuration:

**To restore the options for Layout, Top and bottom margins and frames**, I set the following:

```
$TCA['tt_content']['palettes']['frames']['showitem'] = 'layout;LLL:EXT:cms/locallang_ttc.xlf:layout_formlabel, spaceBefore;LLL:EXT:cms/locallang_ttc.xlf:spaceBefore_formlabel, spaceAfter;LLL:EXT:cms/locallang_ttc.xlf:spaceAfter_formlabel, section_frame;LLL:EXT:cms/locallang_ttc.xlf:section_frame_formlabel';
```

**To restore the appearance tab title:**

In `$TCA['tt_content']['types']['image']['showitem']` I changed `LLL:EXT:frontend/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_ttc.xlf:tabs.appearance` to `LLL:EXT:cms/locallang_ttc.xlf:tabs.appearance`

**To restore the image adjustments:**

In `$TCA['tt_content']['types']['image']['showitem']` I changed `--div--` to `--palette--` right after the frames part and I added `LLL:EXT:cms/locallang_ttc.xlf:palette.image_settings;image_settings,                    --palette--;LLL:EXT:cms/locallang_ttc.xlf:palette.imageblock;imageblock,                --div--;` after the frames part.

This is the result:

```
$TCA['tt_content']['types']['image']['showitem'] = '--palette--;LLL:EXT:cms/locallang_ttc.xlf:palette.general;general,                --palette--;LLL:EXT:cms/locallang_ttc.xlf:palette.header;header,        --div--;LLL:EXT:cms/locallang_ttc.xlf:tabs.images,                image,                --palette--;LLL:EXT:cms/locallang_ttc.xlf:palette.imagelinks;imagelinks,      --div--;LLL:EXT:cms/locallang_ttc.xlf:tabs.appearance,              --palette--;LLL:EXT:frontend/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_ttc.xlf:palette.frames;frames,        --palette--;LLL:EXT:cms/locallang_ttc.xlf:palette.image_settings;image_settings,                    --palette--;LLL:EXT:cms/locallang_ttc.xlf:palette.imageblock;imageblock,                --div--;LLL:EXT:cms/locallang_ttc.xlf:tabs.access,                --palette--;LLL:EXT:cms/locallang_ttc.xlf:palette.visibility;visibility,                --palette--;LLL:EXT:cms/locallang_ttc.xlf:palette.access;access,        --div--;LLL:EXT:cms/locallang_ttc.xlf:tabs.extended, , --div--;LLL:EXT:flux/Resources/Private/Language/locallang.xlf:tt_content.tabs.relation, tx_flux_parent, tx_flux_column, tx_flux_children;LLL:EXT:flux/Resources/Private/Language/locallang.xlf:tt_content.tx_flux_children';
```

**Result**

After making these changes, the result is the following:

[image: result]

Comment: Some ext introduced these damages, use your IDE to find the 'guilty' code and consider disabling it